# Change WebApp ROOT application in tomcat 8 (No WAR file)

Tags: solr, tomcat8, maven

I am trying to change the ROOT application for another one that I installed using Maven but I do not achieve it, the application also uses apache solr.

Is there any way to place both at root level?

And if I would have to recompile it, what would the process be?

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy two webapps using the same context path. You need to change the path for one application, i.e. one can be the root webapp while the other one has a different path.